# Why is this code needed for a TreeViewer from Eclipsepedia?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I found these [JFaceSnippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets) from eclipsepedia. I am particularly interested in the [TreeViewer](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet026TreeViewerTabEditing) but I can not understand the code [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet026TreeViewerTabEditing.java):

```
TreeViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TreeViewerFocusCellManager(v,new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(v));  
ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(v) {  
   protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {  
    return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL  
    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
    || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED &&
             event.keyCode == SWT.CR)
    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;  
  }  
};  
TreeViewerEditor.create(v, focusCellManager, actSupport, ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL| ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR  
 | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION);
```

Why is this specific code snippet needed? If I run the example with this code commented out, there does not seem to be a difference.
So why is this code used and what does it offer in the `TreeViewer`?

Answer (score 3):

This part of the code allows in-place editing of the tree cells, so you can double-click on a node and edit its contents.

This line allows Trees to have "Cells" that can be used for editing.

```
TreeViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TreeViewerFocusCellManager(v,new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(v));
```

This line determines when the cell editor will be activated for inplace editing (Double-click, Enter)

```
ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(v) {  
   protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {  
    return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL  
    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
    || (event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.KEY_PRESSED &&
             event.keyCode == SWT.CR)
    || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;  
  }  
};
```

This line creates the actual editor that will be used to edit the tree cells

```
TreeViewerEditor.create(v, focusCellManager, actSupport, ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL| ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR   | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION);
```

Comment: But the cells can not be edited even when these lines of code are included.I tried it and editing is not possible

Comment: I haven't tried the code, I was trying to describe what it should do :).
The crucial part to support editing is the statement from snippet `column.setEditingSupport(new EditingSupport(v) {...`
If the snippet doesn't work as expected, may be we need to ask Tom Schindl, or file a bug.

Comment: Tom Schindl is the author of the snippet, he is a well known committer in Eclipse. his email is available in the snippet comments, he is also very active in the eclipse forums.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the code, it specifies interaction settings, for example that you can activate a cell by double-clicking and using the enter key and such. Some of these settings might be in alignment with the defaults.